# Rails 4 - showing errors in a model that is not Activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I have a tableless model (i.e not saving in the DB), in order to manage a form. After following the instruction set in a [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model?language=en&view=asciicast) episode, it's mostly working:

```
class PaymentRequest
    include ActiveModel::Validations
    include ActiveModel::Conversion
    extend ActiveModel::Naming

    attr_accessor :request_id, :amount, :description, :reference, :charge_date
    validates :request_id, presence: true
    validates :amount, presence: true, numericality: true
    validates :charge_date, presence: true

    def initialize(attributes = {})
        attributes.each do |name, value|
            send("#{name}=", value)
        end
    end

    def persisted?
        false
    end
end
```

When I do `PaymentRequest.new().valid?`, I get `false` (and vice-versa if it's actually valid).

However I get no error messages whatsoever: when running `PaymentRequest.new().errors.messages` I get an empty hash `{}`.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`errors` only gets populated after you call a validation method, like `valid?`. If you do so, you'll get error messages just like with an ActiveRecord object.

Here's an example, using the `PaymentRequest` code you provided in your question:

```
p = PaymentRequest.new
p.errors.messages # => {}
p.valid? # => false
p.errors.messages # => {:request_id=>["can't be blank"],...
```

Notice how `errors` is initially blank, but gets populated as soon as `valid?` is called.

Comment: Got it - I was testing in the console by running the 2 in sequence. Saving it to a variable made the difference!

Answer (score 0):

Your `errors.messages` hash is empty because you are using `new` method: `PaymentRequest.new()`, so you are not trying to persist anything in the database.

validations are called before an object is persisted in the database e.g. when you try to `save` the object or when you call a validation method.

In your example, if you try to save the payment object, then your `errors.messages` hash will be populated with appropriate messages:

```
p = PaymentRequest.new()
p.errors.messages
# => {} # empty hash because you did not try to save the p object yet
p.save # at this point validations are happening
p.errors.messages 
# => {:charge_date =>["can't be blank"]} . . .
```

Alternatively, you can use: `create` method:

```
p = PaymentRequest.create()
p.errors.messages 
# => {:charge_date =>["can't be blank"]} . . .
```

Then, you will see the error messages in the `errors.messages` hash because `create` method tried to save the object.

To answer your other question, `PaymentRequest.new().valid?` is `false` because everything before saving/persisting is `false`. `valid?` will return `true` when the object is `save`d successfully.

Comment: I might have made it more clear that I am not saving it to the DB (hence the persisted false). valid? works regardless of the persisting (because of the include / extend at the beginning).